# Como inserir um dicionário com foreach utilizando observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Estou tentando criar diversas pessoas no meu banco de dados ao iniciar a aplicação, porém ele só está criando o último usuário.

**APP.COMPONENT**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'webwhatsapp';
    peoples: Array<People> = [
        { id: '0', name: 'THIAGO DE BONIS CARVALHO SAAD SAUD', avatar: 'assets/users/thiagobonis.jpg', messages: null },
        { id: '1', name: 'BILL GATES', avatar: 'assets/users/billgates.jpg', messages: null },
        { id: '2', name: 'STEVE JOBS', avatar: 'assets/users/stevejobs.jpg', messages: null },
        { id: '3', name: 'LINUS TORVALDS', avatar: 'assets/users/linustorvalds.jpg', messages: null },
        { id: '4', name: 'EDSGER DIJKSTRA', avatar: 'assets/users/dijkstra.jpg', messages: null },
    ];

    constructor(public peopleService: PeopleService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.peoples.forEach((people: People) => this.peopleService.create(people));
    }
}
```

**BACKEND SERVICE:**

```
createPeople(people: People): Observable<People> {
    return this.getPeople(people.id).pipe(
        catchError((error) => throwError(error)),
        switchMap(() => {
            return this.httpClient.post<People>(this.SERVER_URL, people).pipe(
                map((data) => data),
                catchError((error) => throwError(error))
            );
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução para esse caso é você retornar observable no seu service, fazer um map para um lista de observables, assim voce pode usar usar o forkJoin (link para a documentação https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin), exemplo de uso:

```
var listaObservables = this.peoples.map((people: People) =>  this.peopleService.create(people));

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(() => {
console.log("sucesso");
})
```